# Not sure how to convert this to Hex?

Tags: c#, enums

This is the pseudo code I have written

```
Color temp = Color.FromArgb(Settings.Default["accentColorSetting"].ToString() + "200");
statusInfo.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(temp.R, temp.G, temp.B);//(R, G, B)
```

The part that is the issue is `Color temp = Color.FromArgb(Settings.Default["accentColorSetting"].ToString() + "200");`

The text inside `"accentColorSetting"` is `Orange` and it is a `string`.

The is the code I'm looking at
[MaterialSkin Code](https://github.com/IgnaceMaes/MaterialSkin/blob/b130c6e8ba38143d8e5c890cf86dc83252959bb4/MaterialSkin/ColorScheme.cs)

I already have it all setup and working, this is the only part I'm having trouble with now.

From what I understand, `Color temp = Color.FromArgb(Settings.Default["accentColorSetting"].ToString() + "200");` requires a Hex color to be placed, so it would take the string that inside the setting, which would be `Orange` and then the Materialskin code that I linked shows this `Orange200 = 0xFFAB40,` So I would like for it to replace `Orange200` with `0xFFAB40`.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Don't you need this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname.aspx What is that `+ 200` for? Why did you use the `enum` tag?

Comment: @Andrew If you click the link to their code, the colors are `enum` and the `+ 200` is the name of the color in the library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need to do:

```
string colorString = Settings.Default["accentColorSetting"].ToString() + "200";
Accent colorEnum;
Enum.TryParse(colorString, out colorEnum);
statusInfo.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb((int)colorEnum);
```

First, find the `enum` that corresponds to your string, and then simply use that value to obtain the corresponding `Color`.

No hex involved actually. Those enums are all integers, it's just that they are written in hex for simpler visual understanding, but they are nothing more than numeric values. You can do `(int)Primary.BlueGrey50` for example and you will see its corresponding numeric value.

Comment: You're amazing =]

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use `Color.FromName` which gives you the color corresponds to the name that you are giving. If so your code will be like the following:

```
Color temp = Color.FromName(Settings.Default["accentColorSetting"].ToString());
```

Where `Settings.Default["accentColorSetting"]` will have a value `orange` as you said. **Note :-** you can add color type entry in settings, that will be another nice idea for you in this case

Answer (score 1):

You can try Enum.TryParse https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx.

`Primary colorValue;
Enum.TryParse("Orange200", out colorValue);`

Comment: TryParse expects an `enum`, not a `Color`.

Comment: Actually, based on the setting used, I guess he wants the `Accent` enum. :D

Comment: Now I am not changing it anymore :). You are right. Your answer already is handling that correctly. Thank you for the comment.